# I tried to run following program of using python 3.9.0 , there is error: 'module' object has no attribute 'div' Can anybody help me

Tags: python

```
#in file calc.py i wrote the following code 

def Div(a,b):

    return a/b

#in another file i wrote following code to import module calc 

import calc

c= calc.Div(4,2)

print(c)
```

Comment: You appear to have imported the wrong file. Are you sure the `calc.py` you want is in the same folder as the file you're importing it into? What does `print(calc.__dict__)` in the second script show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am really very sorry , i got the answer .
i thought vscode saves files automatically , but then i got that we have to run the program in order to save the file .
my code didn't working because i forgot to save calc.py after making changes.

thankyou for your answer , and i hope you all will support me in future for further problems.

i am gratefull to you